# Aliasing Structs in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, events, c++11, alias

I am writing a C++11 program that involves events and callbacks. I have a base class called Event, it's then derived by concrete event classes.

```
template <typename EventArgs>
class Event {
public:
    using EventHandler = std::function<void(EventArgs)>;
    void operator +=(EventHandler handlerDelegate);
    void fire(EventArgs e);
private:
    std::vector<EventHandler> subscribers;
};

struct TouchEventArgs { int x, int y }
struct TouchEvent : public Event<TouchEventArgs> { }
...
```

I was wondering if something like this was possible:

```
template <typename EventArgs>
using event = struct : public Event<EventName> {  };
```

So that i could declare events like

```
event<TouchEventArgs> TouchEvent;
```

Comment: What is the point of declaring `TouchEvent` as subclass of `Event`? Why not just use `Event<TouchEventArgs>`? Or if you need an alias, `using TouchEvent = Event<TouchEventArgs>`.

Comment: In order to preserve encapsulation, I need to subset the possible EventArgs template parameters. A lot of code uses the same events and standardization is needed, so that there wouldn't be any incompatibilities between the passable arguments

Comment: `struct TouchEvent : public Event<TouchEventArgs> {};` is not very long to declare new event type, you may still do macro to shorten that a little, but I don't think it would be really more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain a compile-time mapping between event types and their arg types:

```
namespace detail {
    //primary template
    template <typename EventArgs>
    struct event;

    //the event for TouchEventArgs is TouchEvent
    template<> struct event<TouchEventArgs>
    { using type = TouchEvent; };
}

//helper template
template <typename EventArgs>
using event = typename detail::event<EventArgs>::type;
```

Now we can declare a variable just like you wanted (assuming the name conflict was an accident):

```
event<TouchEventArgs> touch_event; //decltype(TouchEvent) is TouchEvent
```